# listVIew SelectionChanged and StorageFiles

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have a listView with StorageFile elements(as each element represents .mp3 file)

```
<ListView x:Name="songList" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="680" Background="{Binding }" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfStorageFiles , Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   Margin="986,120,0,-80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="294">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

So far I use folderPicker to get specific folder from the user and i bind all the files to the listView as a list of storageFiles. The files show up and im able to select them , but i have to change the mediaElement Source upon listView `SelectionChanged`. Unfortunately when i add SelectionChanged to listView the compiler tells me - `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. Anyone know what cause this behavior ? Also is this the right approach for playing media files from a list(binding the storageFile to the list ).

EDIT : I probably have to use Interaction.Behaviors for EventName = "SelectionChanged" ?

Comment: Can you bind the list view's `SelectedItem` to a property on your VM that represents the current file?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnSelectedSongFromList }" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=songList, Mode=TwoWay}"></core:InvokeCommandAction>

                       </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Then in the VM i use the list to :

```
ListOfMedia.MoveTo((uint)asf.SelectedIndex);
```